# google picker is not woking in react

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, google-picker

[react-google-drive-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-drive-picker)

[react-google-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker)

methods from both package are expired.

response when try to authenticate :

[image]

```
{
  error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  details:"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the Migration Guide for more information."
}
```

Comment: By any chance does the error throws a link in the "See the Migration Guide for more information" part? Those errors usually throws a link where you can check what steps to complete in order to fix the error. Based on the error message, the packages you're using may be deprecated. Instead you may try completing steps from official Google Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs ,  https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview#load-the-google-picker-library and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @LorenaGomez https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample   this is a official documentation from googel to implemented google picker. This one also not updated by google with new identity service. Please request google to upadate all their official documentation when they release new changes

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the packages attached to your question, the creator should update it to authenticate the new way. And answering your comment about updating documentation for Google Picker API with the new Google Identity Service, it seems there is already a feature request and you can refer to this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217414937) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on the same issue for 8 days in a row now. The reason for this error, which as of now is still present using the **react-google-drive-picker** library, is the following code found inside ***picker.ts*** (#40-#47):

```js
await gapi.client.init({
                            immediate: false,
                            ux_mode: 'redirect',
                            apiKey: API_KEY,
                            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                            scope: SCOPES.join(' ')
                        });
```

Because of **clientId** and **scope** this request initializes **gapi.auth2** and this can only be done ***once*** and most likely you're doing it somewhere else too. In other words, a fresh React App would do just fine with the library but one with **Social Login with Google** is likely to have side effects due to calling **gapi.auth2** more than once

More on the subject [Cannot run gapi.client.init multiple times](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/316)

A possible workaround is adding the following script inside your **index.html**

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```